# Display all rows from Mysql table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a **database "media"** with **table "video"**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

table video contains  3 fields:
**id,
title,
link** (contains iframe and link to video).

I want to display all of the videos in the mysql table, but only the first video s being displayed.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM video"); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $id = $row["id"];
  $videoiframe = $row["link"]; 
  }
echo  "{$videoiframe}"; 
?>
```

Comment: You are overwriting the variables in the loop.  You only see the one value, because the variables only contain one value.

Comment: rightly said gordon..echo it from the loop or use "$videoiframe .= "and the array will get appended

Comment: Would a foreach loop fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop override the value of `id and videoiframe`. You need to define an array and store value in it as

```
$array=array();// define array

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $array[] = $row; // Inside while loop
    }
print_r($array);// get all value
```

Updated

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $user.=$row['link']."</br>";
  }
echo $user;
```

Comment: Have tried this. --- $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM video"); 

$array=array();// define array 
    while( $row = $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $array[] = $row; // Inside while loop
    }
print_r($array);// get all value 
?>

Comment: The table contains 3 items, but the code displays "Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 and the video in iframes 6-7 times.

Comment: 3 items in table, but it displays 6.

Comment: post value of `print_r($array)`

Comment: 3 its duplicating. Do I need a counter.?

Comment: value of array shows......Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => test title 1 [title] => test title 1 [2] => iframe code [link] => iframe code ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [id] => 2 [1] => test title 2 [title] => test title 2 [2] => iframe code [link] => iframe code ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 [id] => 3 [1] => test title 3 [title] => test title 3 [2] => iframe code [link] => iframe code ) )

Comment: Use this `$array=array();// define array

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $array[] = $row; // Inside while loop
    }
print_r($array);// get all value`

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: Now shows.....
iframe code,iframe code,iframe code...

Can I get this so that each ".iframe code" is under each other like: 

iframe code
iframe code
iframe code

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $user.=$row['link']
  }
echo $user;`

Comment: It shows the "iframe" tiled horizontally. Can I get this to show them tied vertically.?

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $user.=$row['link']."</br>" } echo $user;`